# Why are the labels on my D3 axis inconsistent (e.g. month, day)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a D3 X axis that has a time scale.

The x axis labels are appearing inconsistently:

```
Sat 09 Aug 10 Mon 11 Tue 12 Wed 13 Thu 14 Fri 15 Sat 16 Aug 17
```

I've put my code in this fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/vh343kmc/2/

I think this is a time formatting issue but I am not sure. Any idea as to what is going wrong?

Comment: D3 is using a multi-scale time format by default (see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#tickFormat)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a good time format written, but you need to tell your `xAxis` to use it:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickSize(1)
    .tickFormat(format) // <------ add this line
    .orient("bottom");
```

Here's what the axis will change to. (Note that you might need to tweak how you draw the axis due to size constraints.)

[image: updated axis]