# Different xAxis ticks in dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have next chart:

```
chart
  .renderArea(true)
  .width(width)
  .height(400)
  .dimension(dim)
  .group(group, "Strategy")
  .x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDateWithDelta, endDateWithDelta]))
  .round(d3.time.day.round)
  .xUnits(d3.time.days)
  .elasticY(true)
  .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
  .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
  .useRightYAxis(true)
  .yAxisPadding("20%")
  .xAxis().ticks(8);
```

You can see screenshot below.

[image]

Why my xAxis render one more vertical line for November month? I want to have the same size for every square in my chart. Maybe I have some errors in chart's configuration?

*UPDATE:*

My data example:

```
[{
  timestamp: "2016-09-13T00:00:00",
  profitPercent: 0
},
...
{
  timestamp: "2016-09-25T00:00:00",
  profitPercent: 1.45
}]
```

Comment: I think there might be an error in your dataset also because some ticks are showing months and some others are showing days of week. Can you provide an example of your data?

Comment: xAxis shows a different type of points like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831783/why-are-the-labels-on-my-d3-axis-inconsistent-e-g-month-day). But when I add that code, point with `November` still in the same position. I added some data example to post

Comment: I think the issue is that d3.svg.axis automatically adds month ticks when the data is in days. One solution would be to use `tickValues` instead of `ticks` and manually specify the ticks you want.